# I'm trying to play games on my TV from my PC, but I am experiencing input lag

Tags: hdmi, gaming, tv, steam

I connected my PC to my living room TV using a long HDMI cable and a USB extendor to connect an xbox one controller adaptor to it, so I could play wirelessly on the couch.

TV is a 4k Samsung TV, but I don't run games in 4K since it's too demanding. I have game mode turned on, and I registered the input as PC.

Is there anything else I can do to reduce input delay/lag? It is quite noticible, and makes it harder to play some games. I don't plan on playing anything multiplayer on the couch, just single player story games.

Answer (score 0):

the lag could be on the usb extender side of things. But recent model Samsung TVs can be a bit fussy about not fully turning on game mode for computer inputs so that's also a potential issue. The menu will show that game mode is on, but the performance will be somewhat slower than for a true console.